# How to split the contents of $left which shows the navigation links in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I was integrating a custom theme on to my project and i got stuck with this.The variable $left prints the navigation links on the sidebar.Actually when i print $left i get this auto-generated code shown below...But i need only the < ul> content...could some one please help me with it.....

```
< div>< class="clear-block block block-user" id="block-user-1">

 < div>< class="content">

  < ul class="menu">

      < li class="leaf first">< a href="/?q=Test">My Account< /a>< /li>

      < li class="leaf">< a href="/?q=Test2">My Books< /a>< /li>

 </ul>

< /div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here is what i found out...I don't know if there is any other method for this.
There is a **block.tpl.php** file that is used for each and every blocks that you have in your theme.I found this code in the block.tpl.php

```
<div id="block- <?php print $block->module .'-'. $block->delta; ?>" class="clear-block block block-<?php print $block->module ?>">

<?php if (!empty($block->subject)): ?>
<h2>< ?php print $block->subject ?></h2>
<?php endif;?>
<div class="content"><?php print $block->content ?>< /div>
</div>
```

For a custom layout for a block by region you just need to create a tpl file for the region using the following standard: **block-*regionname*.tpl.php**.So if that region was the "**custom**" then you would create a file called **block-custom.tpl.php** in you theme folder and paste the code that gives u the content of the block.

```
<?php print $block->content ?>
```

and off you go.... :)